# Using loops to create multiple matplotlib graphs with dual y-axes

Tags: loops, matplotlib

I am trying to create a number of time-series graphs using matplotlib for sales of different kind of fruits and their average selling price over time using loops.  Each graph has the following identical characteristics:

- Selling price (yield) the left y-axis, daily selling volume (ADV) on the right y-axis
- Time (months) on the x-axis
- Graph title with each y-axis series labeled
- Shading (represents a forecast)
- Vertical reference line (to represent a change in business rules)

Here is a sample:

[image]

I wrote some matplotlib code to create one graph and it works fine.  Now I want to take the code and using loops create the same type of graphs for many fruit products without creating each 1-by-1 since the  template is the same, just the title and plotted series in each graph changes.  The code doesn't run, it doesn't even give an error message.  How to fix?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

# Set figure Size
fig.set_figwidth(8)
fig.set_figheight(6)

x_col = "date"
title=['Apple Metrics: ADV and Yield Over Time','Banana Metrics: ADV and Yield Over Time','Pear Metrics: ADV and Yield Over Time']
y1_col = ["apple_yld", "banana_yld", "pear_yld"]
y2_col = ["apple_adv", "banana_adv", "pear_adv"]
start_date='2015-01-01'
end_date='2021-12-01'
start_date_of_shading='2020-06-01'
end_date_of_shading='2023-05-01'


for x_col in y1_col and y2_col:

# Graph title
    fig.suptitle(title,fontsize=20)

# set x label which is common / set left y-axis label / set labelcolor and labelsize to the left Y-axis
    mygraph.set_xlabel('Date (Monthly Frequency)')
    mygraph.set_ylabel('Yield (inverted scale)', color='red',size='x-large')
    mygraph.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='red', labelsize='large')

# plot fruit Yield on left Y-axis; invert axis 
    mygraph.plot(df2[x_col], df2[y1_col], color='red',linewidth=3.0)
    mygraph.invert_yaxis()
    mygraph.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.2f}'))
    mygraph.axvline(pd.Timestamp('2019-06-01'),color='green', linestyle='--',linewidth=4.0)  

# twinx sets the same x-axis for both plots / set right y-axis label / set labelcolor and labelsize to the right Y-axis
    mygraph_1 = mygraph.twinx()
    mygraph_1.set_ylabel('ADV', color='blue', size='x-large') 
    mygraph_1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='blue',labelsize='large')
    mygraph.set_xlim(['2015-01-01','2019-12-01'])

# plot fruit ADV on right Y-axis, format with comma separator  
    mygraph_1.plot(df2[x_col], df2[y2_col], color='blue',linewidth=3.0)
    mygraph_1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `plt.subplots()`, it returns a tuple of figure and axes objects. axes in this particular case will be an array of shape (rows x cols). And you can assign each one of your items into the appropriate axis location as shown below:

```
rows=len(y1_col) #set the desired number of rows
cols=2 #set the desired number of columns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(13,8),sharex=False,sharey=False) # if you want to turn off sharing axis.
row=0 #to iterate over rows/cols
col=0 #to iterate over rows/cols
for item_num in range(len(y1_col)):

    ax[row][col].plot(df2[x_col], df2[y1_col[item_num]], color='red',linewidth=3.0)
    ax[row][col].set_xlabel('Date (Monthly Frequency)')
    ax[row][col].set_ylabel('Yield (inverted scale)', color='red',size='x-large')
    ax[row][col].tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='red', labelsize='large')
    ax[row][col].invert_yaxis()
    ax[row][col].yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.2f}'))
    ax[row][col].axvline(pd.Timestamp('2019-06-01'),color='green', linestyle='--',linewidth=4.0)  


    axp = ax[row][col].twinx()
    axp.plot(df2[x_col], df2[y2_col[item_num]], color='blue',linewidth=3.0)
    axp.set_ylabel('ADV', color='blue', size='x-large') 
    axp.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='blue',labelsize='large')
    axp.set_xlim(['2015-01-01','2019-12-01'])


    col=col+1
    if col==1:
        row=row
    else:
        row=row+1
        col=0

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks...when I run your code I am getting an error message stating "name 'y1_col' is not defined".  How do I fix this?

Comment: You have it defined in your code: y1_col = ["apple_yld", "banana_yld", "pear_yld"]

Comment: This looks good!  Two quick follow-ups: (1) How do you code this to include a custom title for each of the 3 graph: Apple Trends, Banana Trends, Pear Trends and (2) How do make the graphs as individual graphs rather than in a grid like fashion?  When I view them they appear a bit squished.

Comment: Happy to help. If you found the answer helpful and it solved your problem, you want to check the green mark. This helps keep the focus on unanswered questions. For your follow up questions: 1) check for set_title option for each axis element, e.g. ax[row][column].set_title 2) you can adjust the plot size by adjusting `figsize` in `plt.subplots`() appropriately.